# SP2010 DVWP Group By Multi-choice lookup list

Tags: xslt, data-view-web-part, grouping

I currently have a column which is a multi-choice lookup list, I'd like to create a row for each multi-choice items per row and group by the multi-choice column.

I've tried using XSLT to format the multi-choice strings (separated by ;#') using spxslt however I still cannot figure out the code for grouping.

An example of what I'm after

Application Lookup List

> MSWord
>
> MSExcel

Document Library

> DocNumber1 | MSWord; MSExcel

DVWP

```
MSWord
        DocNumber1

MSExcel
        DocNumber1
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This article on EndUserSharePoint explains how:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/sharepoint-group-by-a-column-with-multiple-values.aspx

You basically need to create a linked data source to the lookup list and the main list with the join option.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to hide the look-up list headers when the row count is 0, rather than displaying the header and dvt_2.empty?

Comment: You're in control of the XSL. Just change it.